# Finding a list of related objects by ID

Tags: java, kotlin, orm, apache-cayenne

Let's say for example I have a bridge table called `PersonAnimal`. I want to search for all the people who have a given animal's ID. The query so far looks like:

```
Animal animal = getById(Animal.class, animalId)
ObjectSelect
    .query(PersonAnimal.class)
    .where(PersonAnimal.ANIMAL.eq(animal))
    .select(context)
```

However the first line in the above code segment shows that I first have to retrieve the related object from the database. I want to get rid of that database lookup and instead do something like:

```
ObjectSelect
    .query(PersonAnimal.class)
    .where(PersonAnimal.ANIMAL_ID.eq(animalId)) // <- Find by ID instead
    .select(context)
```

Is that possible?

I am running version 4.1 of the Apache Cayenne ORM.

Comment: Version 4.1 of what exactly?  Did you try reading: https://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.0/objectidquery.html ?

Comment: @sofend: Ah sorry I didn't add Apache Cayenne. With regards to your link, I did look at that but that's for finding one object by ID and not a list of objects by ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I posted the question I found the answer. You need to create an `Expression` using a `Property` object like so:

```
val findByIdExpr = Property.create(PersonAnimal.ANIMAL.name, Long::class.java).eq(yourId)
val gotList = ObjectSelect
   .query(PersonAnimal.class)
   .where(findByIdExpr)
   .select(context)
```

Above code is in Kotlin but is also easy to understand from a Java perspective.