# Finding a list of objects by Primary Key ID - Apache Cayenne

Tags: java, kotlin, orm, apache-cayenne

This is kind of related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53563264/3526705) where I discussed finding rows by foreign key IDs. This question is directed at finding a list of objects by primary key ID.

In the below code I am trying to find a list of `Person` objects by providing a list of ids. But Apache Cayenne cannot do that because `ID_PK_COLUMN` is a string and not a `Property`.

```
ObjectSelect
    .query(Person::class.java)
    .where(Person.ID_PK_COLUMN.in(listOfIds)) // <- Cannot perform this
    .select(context)
```

How can I find a list of Person objects by ID?

I know we have `Cayenne.objectForPK` but that only finds one object.

Using Apache Cayenne 4.1.

Comment: What do you get from just:
`val expression = Person.ID_PK_COLUMN.in(listOfIds)`
?

Comment: @AndreArtus: Well, `Person.ID_PK_COLUMN` returns a `String` so the `.in()` method does not work on it, which is why I wrote that I can't perform `.in()` on that particular expression. I think @andrus solved my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ids are generally not mapped as object properties in Cayenne and "ID_PK_COLUMN" is a "db:" property, you need to build a "db" expression for the "where" method argument. There's an API for that:

```
ExpressionFactory.inDbExp(Person.ID_PK_COLUMN, listOfIds)
```

(BTW, `Property` is just syntactic sugar on top of `ExpressionFactory`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. Apache Cayenne is so powerful and fast, I wish more people knew about it.